# Jquery detect change with bootstrap mask on

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following input field:

```
 <input type="text" id="myinput">
```

Using this jquery mask plugin:

```
 jQuery(function($)
     {
        $("#myinput").mask("(999) 999-9999", 
        {
            placeholder:" ",
        });
    });
```

I am trying to detect changes made to this input field using this:

```
$('#myinput').on('input', function() {
        //Change handled here
});
```

With this code, nothing is happening when the input field is being edited. Any help with this simple problem would be appreciated.

Here is a link to the plugin website: [Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: The plugin has a `onChange` callback. Define it in the `options` argument (search for `Callback Examples` on the link you posted)

Comment: $.change(function(){ ... });

Comment: I tried to use the callback options for the mask as shown in the documentation, but none of them are getting called. What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```
$('#myinput').keyup(function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
    })
```

Comment: I just tried the keyup solution, but it was still not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myinput").mask("(999) 999-9999", 
        {
            placeholder:" ",
            onKeyPress: function(cep, event, currentField, options){
                //TODO::
            }
        });
```